# Why I am getting array[i] value of for loop is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to nodeJs. In for loop I am getting array[i] value undefined after get the data from some url. I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me.

Here is my code

```
urls =['url1','url2','url3','url4']
 for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  console.log(urls[i]) // getting value
  var opt = {
    url :urls[i],
      headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer '+reply
    } 
   }
  request.get(opt,function(error,response,body) {
     console.log(urls[i]) // getting undefined
     if(!error) {
        enrichment_data.push({type:body});
     } else {
     enrichment_data.push({type:''})
   }
 })
}
```

Comment: Change `var i` to `let i` for lexical scope. To understand your problem, also try `console.log(i)` in the problematic location as well.

Comment: `urls[i].url` is undefined

Comment: @PatrickRoberts of course you are right. My mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MDN, this type of logical error in understanding JavaScript closures, is [a common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake).

There are two practical ways to solve this. Sticking with ES5 only, the most canonical way to solve this would be to use [`urls.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead:

```
var urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4']

urls.forEach(function(url, i) {
  console.log(urls[i]) // getting value
  var opt = {
    url: urls[i],
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + reply
    }
  }
  request.get(opt, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(urls[i]) // getting undefined
    if (!error) {
      enrichment_data.push({
        type: body
      });
    } else {
      enrichment_data.push({
        type: ''
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Using this method, you create a new function scope that preserves the value of each `i`, even within the asynchronous function, so that the variable reference doesn't get overwritten by later iterations of the `for` loop you had earlier.

Your second option would be to introduce ES6 lexical scope variable declarations using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Cleaner_code_in_inner_functions) like so:

```
var urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4']

for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  console.log(urls[i]) // getting value
  var opt = {
    url: urls[i],
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + reply
    }
  }
  request.get(opt, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(urls[i]) // getting undefined
    if (!error) {
      enrichment_data.push({
        type: body
      });
    } else {
      enrichment_data.push({
        type: ''
      })
    }
  })
})
```

*Lexical scope* means that any reference to `i` inside the block scope of the for loop, even within the body of the asynchronous function, will reference *that particular iteration* of the `for` loop, allowing it to behave as it appears like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Patrick. I wanted to add few points.

To answer the question, why you are getting `undefined` at `console.log(urls[i])` because the value of `i` is 4 and nothing is present at index `4`.

Now to the point why i is 4. `request` is an async call and once you call `request.get`, it goes through event loop and gets written to the stack (with the right url) to be called. . This stack would be called only when the current call is over, which is after your `for` loop is over. Your loops gets over only when i is 4 and `var` is global scope

Here is a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) to understand how event loop works.

Comment: oh i thought it would be a scope problem : `i` shouldn't exist outside the loop so it shouldn't exist in the request's `console.log()`

Comment: If I run this
```const request = require('request');
const urls =['http://www.google.com','http://bing.com','https://duckduckgo.com'];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  console.log(urls[i]) // getting value
  var opt = {
    url :urls[i]
   }
  request.get(opt,function(error,response,body) {
     console.log(i);
     if(!error) {
       console.log('success');
     } else {
      console.log('failure');
   }
 });
}```

The output is
```3
success
3
success
3
success```